# Как лучше хранить информацию о двух массивах сообщений, если изначально это просто string

Tags: c#, .net, строки, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

У меня есть переменная типа string HistoryBody; по идеи там должно храниться текст в виде сообщений *(как в телеграмме)*, то-есть :

```
Пользователь1: ......
Пользователь2: ......
Пользователь1: ......
```

Вопросы:

1. Как я могу из простого string разбить на два Пользователя, и управлять самими сообщения например через индекс(List/Array)?
2. (не столь важный, могу и сам понять): Как это правильно сделать, что-бы оно подходило еще под asp.net MVC

Comment: Почему оно в текстовом файле? Ведь структурированные данные проще всего хранить например в базе данных, а сериализовать в json или xml. Быть может стоит подумать, а как их лучше сохранить, чтобы потом было проще прочитать?

Comment: Правило этого сайта: одна тема - один вопрос. / Второй вопрос задайте отдельным сообщением. Отмечу, что в ASP.NET MVC можно использовать Model Binding для приёма данных в любом формате, Formatters для отдачи данных в любом формате.

Comment: Спасибо, создам другой вопрос что бы разобраться с этой темой